# Using C# WATIN, how do I get the value of a INPUT tag html element?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, watin

Using C#  WATIN, how do I get the value of the second occurence of a INPUT tag html element on a page?

I've tried a whole bunch of things and haven't succeeded.  The debugger isn't giving me any obvious way to get element[1] among the 4 that returned.

```
Console.WriteLine(ie.Element(Find.ByClass("myclass")).GetAttributeValue("value")  ) ;  
// works but prints the value of the 1st of 4 input elements on the page

Console.WriteLine(ie.ElementsWithTag("input", "text").Length.ToString()  ); 
// returns the number 4

Console.WriteLine( ie.Element(Find.ByName("login")).GetAttributeValue("value")  );
// works but its not safe since its possible there might be two elements with the name login
```

Basically, I want to be able to select the input element by its **array index**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can help:

```
        ElementCollection elementCol = ie.Elements;
        elementCol = elementCol.Filter(Find.ByClass("myclass"));
        string value = elemntCol[1].GetAttributeValue("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ie.Element(Find.ByIndex(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't anybody use loops anymore? I think loops are neat (and a whole lot easier on the comprehension of why Watin exhibits this behavior / stole my lunch ;-) :

```
TextFieldCollection textFields = browser.TextFields;  
foreach (var field in textFields)  
{  
    if (field.Id == "humbuggery")...  
}
```

Comment: ...more loop-like, I meant :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I may have accidentally ran across a better answer from [index constraint class](http://watin.sourceforge.net/doc/T_WatiN_Core_Constraints_IndexConstraint.html), which is:

```
ie.Link(new IndexConstraint(1) && Find.ByName("linkname"))
```

I need to research it.  I'll revisit this question later.